# My github page link showing blank white page

Tags: github

To get your site working again you'll need to make sure your repository is set to public again, head to the repository settings page, make sure that GitHub Pages is enabled, then push a fresh commit to your repository.

Answer (score -1):

A page will only show up automatically if there is a file called `index.html` or `readME.md` in the head directory (Not in any folders). You have neither of them. To see the pages you need to put the file path in as well. For the HTML file, you have in the repository you need to go to the following URL.
`https://ramirezhans.me/public/index.html`